# Current beside the passive element (or generic) instead of before or after

Tags: arrows, generic

I wanted to draw following circuit in latex
[image]

I could get the following:
[image]

Which is perfect except that I want the current symbol and label  to be on top/bottom or left/right of the generic element rather than before or after (which I currently ended p with). Is there an easy way I could achieve this?
My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{
    generic/.append style={color=cyan},
    cute inductor/.append style={color=cyan},
    I/.append style={color=red},
    V/.append style={color=red},
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american,scale=.8]
    \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.8, sources/scale=.8}
    \draw (0,0)
    to [V, l=9<\volt>,invert]           ++(0,3)
    to [generic, f<=$ i_1 $]    ++(3,0)
    to [short]                  ++(3,0)
    to [I,l=0.5<\ampere>,invert]        ++(3,0)
    to [generic,f>=$ i_4 $]     ++(0,-3)
    to (0,0)
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    (3,3) to [generic,v<=$ v_2 $,*-*]   ++(0,-3)
    (6,3) to [generic,v>=$ v_3 $,*-*]   ++(0,-3)
 ;
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{PSC 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than attempt to change how circuitikz positions current arrows (been there, done that, not fun), this solution overlays current arrows for a `open` component, with a little tweaking to correct the offset.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{
    generic/.append style={color=cyan},
    cute inductor/.append style={color=cyan},
    I/.append style={color=red},
    V/.append style={color=red},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american,scale=.8]
    \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.8, sources/scale=.8}
    \draw (0,0)
    to [V, l=9<\volt>,invert]           ++(0,3)
    to [generic, name=A]    ++(3,0)
    to [short]                  ++(3,0)
    to [I,l=0.5<\ampere>,invert]        ++(3,0)
    to [generic,name=B]     ++(0,-3)
    to (0,0)
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    (3,3) to [generic,v<=$ v_2 $,*-*]   ++(0,-3)
    (6,3) to [generic,v>=$ v_3 $,*-*]   ++(0,-3)
 ;
\draw ($(A.west)+(-0.4cm,4pt)$) to[open, f=$ i_1 $] ($(A.east)+(-0.4cm,4pt)$)
      ($(B.west)+(4pt,0.4cm)$) to[open, f=$ i_4 $] ($(B.east)+(4pt,0.4cm)$);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks John. I believe you and will use the solution you recommend. However, a slight problem ... I get this weird line in the generic element where the current lines are drawn. 
It inside the elements. I wish I could attached my image but I don't know how to attach it in the comment.

Comment: All I can advise is to make sure your package is up to date.

Comment: I will check that. BTW, how can I attach image in a comment?

Comment: Put an image into an answer, link to the answer then delete (hide) it.